# c# multiple sorting

Tags: c#, sorting

I have 3 levels for a PlanSolution 1,2,3 and i need to sort by .levelId initially, and then alphabetically sort the solutions belonging to that level by .name

```
PlanSolution[] planSolutions = wsAccess.GetPlanSolutionsForPlanRisk(planRisk.Id);
                    List<PlanRisk> planSolutionsList = new List<PlanRisk>(planSolutions);


                    planSolutionsList.Sort(delegate(PlanSolution x, PlanSolution y)
                    {
                        //HELP lol
                    });
```

Comment: You don't need to create a `List<T>` just to do sorting.  Just use the `Array.Sort()` method as well as one of the delegates provided in the many solutions.  Linq may be overkill if your array is large, as it may require you to make a copy of it if you want to keep it as an array or list (via `ToList()` or `ToArray()`).

Answer (score 6):

LINQ to the rescue!

```
planSolutionsList = planSolutions
    .OrderBy(x => x.id)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
    .ToList(); // is this necessary?
```

For the original format -- you just want your comparer to prioritize ID over name

```
planSolutionsList.Sort( (x, y) => 
{
   //HELP lol
   if (x.id != y.id) return x.id - y.id;
   else return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use Linq

```
planSolutionsList.OrderBy(x => x.Level).ThenBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

For a language-acnostic approach: Do each one in order.

1) Sort on the level.
2) Remember the starting locations of each level after sorting
3) repeat for next sorting crieteria, only sorting the sub-sections.

Answer (score 0):

```
  planSolutionsList.Sort(delegate(PlanSolution x, PlanSolution y) {
    if (x.Level == x.Level) {            // same level, compare by name
      return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
    } else {                             // different level, compare by level
      return x.Level.CompareTo(y.Level);
    }
  });
```